# Need help with a tough SQL query

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a query that I am currently getting the ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row error on.  I understand the error, and what is causing it, but cant figure out a way to fix it.  I would also like to do this in just one query.  Here is what I currently have:

```
SELECT   v1.internal_code,
       (SELECT   terms_id
          FROM   terms
         WHERE   term_start_date =
                    (SELECT   MIN (term_start_date)
                       FROM   terms
                      WHERE   terms_id LIKE '%SU'
                              AND term_start_date >
                                    (SELECT   term_start_date
                                       FROM      terms
                                              JOIN
                                                 vals
                                              ON terms_id =
                                                    internal_code
                                      WHERE   internal_code =
                                                 v1.internal_code
                                              AND valcode_id =
                                                    'TERMS')))
          AS mmTerm
FROM      terms
       JOIN
          vals v1
       ON terms_id = internal_code
  WHERE   internal_code LIKE '%SP' AND valcode_id = 'WEB.SEARCH.TERMS'
 ORDER BY   mmTerm ASC
```

And the relevant part of the vals table would be this:

```
internal_code      valcode_id
-------------      ----------
   2003SP            TERMS
   2004SP            TERMS
   2005SP            TERMS
```

Okay, so the big subquery is attempting to get any terms that end with 'SU' where the term_start_date is greater than the term_start_date of the terms in the vals table.  So the desired result is:

```
v1.internal_code      mmTerm
----------------      ------
    2003SP            2003SU
    2004SP            2004SU
    2005SP            2005SU
```

I know this is tough to understand, so please ask questions if there are any.   Also, any suggestions are gladly accepted.  Thanks!

EDIT:   I figured it out.  Just had to do some reworking, thanks for the suggestions.  I will post it if anyone is interested in seeing the final query

Comment: Is it mysql or microsoft sql server?

Comment: This I am not sure of, I am using Toad with Oracle 10g.  Does that sound right?

Comment: This seems to imply that there are multiple rows in `terms` with the same value for `term_start_date`.  Is that the case and if so, why?  It doesn't seem that multiple terms should have the same start date.

Comment: I dont believe that is the case...... but WHERE terms_id LIKE '%SU'    there are multiple start dates for all summer terms

Comment: @Jonathan What about `Select top 1 term_start_date` in the subquery instead of `Select term_start_date`. if `top 1` doesnt work, end the query with `limit 1`

Comment: @reggie I tried all of those, and also tried AND ROWNUM = 1, but then I get the same error on the outer subquery

Comment: what does your subquery return when run seperately? How many rows does it return when run seperately

Comment: The most inner subquery returns a lot of term_start_dates

Comment: Your first goal is to make the inner most subquery to return only one data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite hard to read - you need to add aliases to all the table references. The error can be gotten around if you don't care about which row the subquery returns - simply return MIN(terms_id) or MAX(terms_id) or whatever to only bring back 1 row. But you may need to think about your data more deeply - does it really matter which term the subquery returns?

```
SELECT   v1.internal_code,
       (SELECT   MIN(terms_id)
          FROM   terms
         WHERE   term_start_date =
                    (SELECT   MIN (term_start_date)
                       FROM   terms
                      WHERE   terms_id LIKE '%SU'
                              AND term_start_date >
                                    (SELECT   term_start_date
                                       FROM      terms
                                              JOIN
                                                 vals
                                              ON terms_id =
                                                    internal_code
                                      WHERE   internal_code =
                                                 v1.internal_code
                                              AND valcode_id =
                                                    'TERMS')))
          AS mmTerm
FROM      terms
       JOIN
          vals v1
       ON terms_id = internal_code
  WHERE   internal_code LIKE '%SP' AND valcode_id = 'WEB.SEARCH.TERMS'
 ORDER BY   mmTerm ASC
```

Comment: I know that min/max return only one row, but that isnt the problem here.  I need the corresponding summer term to each spring term.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in subquery that is used here: `AND term_start_date > ...`

It must return a single value. The best solution I think is to use `MAX()`:

```
AND term_start_date >
    (SELECT MAX(term_start_date) -- USE MAX HERE
    FROM terms
    JOIN vals
    ON terms_id = internal_code
    WHERE internal_code = v1.internal_code
    AND valcode_id = 'TERMS')
```

Using `MAX()` means `term_start_date` must be greater than *all* `term_start_date` found in the subquery).

If you need it to be greater than *any*, use `MIN()` instead.

**EDITED** I swear you have edited your original query! Anyway, try using an aggregate on the outer select, like this:

```
SELECT   v1.internal_code,
   (SELECT   MAX(terms_id)
      FROM   terms
      ...
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this, unfortunately if you use MAX(term_start_date) you will get the same error, but on the entire subquery.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Because I think you are wrong: There is no other place to get that error, and using MAX fixes that problem

Comment: @Bohemian: The outermost subquery can produce the same error - see my answer

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, and the outer subquery gets the same error.  havent had time to sort out why that one gets an error though.

Comment: @Jonathan What about `Select top 1 term_start_date` in the subquery instead of `Max(term_start_date)`. if `top 1` doesnt work, end the query with `limit 1`

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting only one record to match the subquery conditions?
Than you should add a TOP 1 to your  subquery:

```
...
(SELECT TOP 1 terms_id ...
```

Comment: That isnt the part of the subquery that gets the error.  The most inner subquery is where the error occurs   (SELECT term_start_date.....).  So it almost seems like the entire query needs to be wrapped by another subquery, but I havent quite figured it out yet

Comment: Ok, there is another one, right. See the answer of @Bohemian. But the outer subquery has the same problem: It will return more than one row.